# Why isn't my jQuery connecting and why doesn't my forms data save to my javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to recreate account creation through javascript objects while also starting practice in jQuery. However, I am having a few issues.

First, I can't seem to get jQuery to connect. I have tried a few of the recommended methods on the website like downloading through terminal using npm and importing it from other sites that host it. But I keep getting this error "account.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

My second issue is I can't seem to get my form submission data to run through my formSubmit and accountCreation function. I know it's not running because none of the values are popping up in the console log when formSubmit runs. I am really confused on where all the values are going.

I understand I haven't been asking questions right the past few times and they haven't been well received. I am trying to get it right this time. If I need to adjust my question in anyway please let me know. I also understand I will need a database to actually save data at all times but I am just trying to learn objects and constructors right now and thought this would be a good way to practice it. Any tips help, thank you.

edit: I found some issues like undefined variables and trying to use .innerText instead of .textContent. I also realized I cant push an array thats initialized from the outside without changing its variable type and I couldn't use an array to store these objects in general. I updated the code, fixing some of the issues. Still can't get jQuery to connect and would love some advice or steps I could take to find the issue.

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

$(".terms").css("color", "red");

function formSubmit(){
    let user = document.querySelector(".userBox").textContent;
    let email = document.querySelector(".emailBox").textContent;
    let pass = document.querySelector(".passBox").textContent;
    let conPass = document.querySelector(".conPassBox").textContent;
    console.log(user);
    console.log(user + " " + email + " " + pass + " " + conPass);
    accountCreation(user, email, pass, conPass);
}

function accountCreation(user, email, pass, conPass){
    this.username = user;
    this.email1 = email;
    this.password = pass;
    this.confirmPass = conPass;
    console.log(username + " " + email1 + " " + password + " " + confirmPass);
}
```

```css
#form {
    background-color: rgb(30, 10, 80, 0.7);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid white;
    margin: 10% auto;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 55vh;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

#box {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}

.signUpTitle {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 110px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.all {
    padding-top: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: 10px;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.textbox {
    width: 210px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: 15px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#terms {
    border: none;
    padding-left: 250px;
}

.check:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.terms {
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: system-ui;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
}

#submit {
    border: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 240px;
}

.submit {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(80, 20, 200);
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.submit:hover {
    background-color: rgb(80, 25, 190);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#signUp {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 195px;
    color: white;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: none;
}

.signUp {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
            <form id="form">
                <fieldset id="box">
                    <h1 class="signUpTitle">Universal Sign Up</h1>
                    <label for="user" class="user all">Username: </label>
                    <input required type="text" class="userBox textbox" name="user" maxlength="16" minlength="5"></br>
                    <label for="email" class="email all">Email: </label>
                    <input required type="email" class="emailBox textbox" name="email"></br>
                    <label for="pass" class="pass all">Password: </label>
                    <input required type="password" class="passBox textbox" name="pass" maxlength="20" minlength="8"></br>
                    <label for="conPass" class="conPass all" >Confirm password: </label>
                    <input required type="password" class="conPassBox textbox" name="conPass" maxlength="20" minlength="8"></br>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="terms">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
                    <label for="terms" class="terms">Terms and Conditions</label></br>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="submit">
                    <input type="button" class="submit" onclick="formSubmit()">
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="signUp">
                    Already have an account? 
                    <a href="login.html" class="signUp">Sign in</a>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <script src="../src/account.js"></script>
        </main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jquery is really big so we have to wait for it to load or javascript finishes running the whole file without it: 
 script.onload = function () {
// jQuery is available now
 $(".terms").css("color", "red");
 $("title").html("jquery works now");
```

};

Comment: in other words it takes a second or so to load the jQuery file from google.  But javascript doesnt wait and gets to the jQuery code before it loads.  This happens a lot in AJAX when we're waiting for data, and therefore we have promises (used to be success functions (wait till the remote file loads, then continue...)

Comment: note the function end tag diddnt get spaced into my answer above:

Answer (score 0):

You can try the word jQuery: jQuery() (typed out) instead $(). of easier is this; try to get jQuery back to no conflict mode.  This is the easiest:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
/* in here, $ is safe */ 
 }); 

 jQuery(function($) { 
/* in here, $ is safe */ 
 });
```

Comment: I guess you can think of this as a shortcut $() for this jQuery(), but its a little more complicated; its a no conflict mode

Comment: getting the error that "jQuery is not defined" now. It was worth a shot, I think Im just not importing it right or something but this is my first time working with it so I have no idea.

Comment: make sure you're spelling it right

Comment: jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
     });

Comment: Its cap sensitive

Comment: var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $(".terms").css("color", "red");}); 

this is what I have written currently

Comment: gosh that comment did not format well haha sorry if its hard to read

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257101/discussion-between-jim-vanpetten-and-aidanbh16).